# Не запускается процесс process.start()

Tags: c#, процесс

При выполнении программы не запускается процесс

```
 Process.Start(“TslGame.exe”)
```

Процессы типа блокнота, хрома и т.д. работают правильно, а некоторые выдают ошибку связанную с 32 битами. Как лечить?

Comment: Текст ошибки какой?

Comment: Возможно стоит указывать ещё и workingdirectory у процессов, некоторые ожидают, что их запустят из своей папки

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, Process.Start пытается найти зарегистрированное в системе имя (как notepad, calc), если не сработало, то он воспринимает строку, как относительный путь к файлу рабочей директории приложения, иначе он начинает интерпретировать путь как абсолютный, на этом этапе вы и получаете ошибку из-за того, что файл по такому пути не найден. Ведь этот файл может путь вида:

"C:\Program Files\Tsl\TslGame.exe"

Согласитесь, такое поведение метода Start логично, и уж точно лучше, чем если бы вы ждали около минуты, пока не просканируются все директории вашего жесткого диска. Т.е. вам нужно указать полный путь до файла (зажмите Shift и через ПКМ сможете выбрать пункт контекстного меню "Копировать как путь").

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло, вроде пробовал, но не тот exe файл в пути открывал.